# ArrayList loses elements after onChildAdded (Android Studio & Firebase)

Tags: android, database, firebase

```
public void readUniversity(){
    ChildEventListener uniListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey());
            University uni = dataSnapshot.getValue(University.class);
            universitieslist.add(uni); //Adding to an ArrayList of type University
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, universitieslist.size()+"is the size");
            arrayofUniversities.add(uni.getName()); //Adding name of University to list
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, adapter.getCount() + " items");
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, arrayofUniversities.size()+" is the size");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    DatabaseReference uniReference = database.getReference("note-retrieve/Universities");
    uniReference.addChildEventListener(uniListener);
}
```

The code is pretty much self explanatory. I am using arrayofUniversities a list to populate a spinner so I need an adapter. I am populating the spinner with the names of the Universities

I am storing the University Objects in universitieslist

The problem I have is when I leave the readUniversity() method I lose every element in universitieslist and arrayofUniversities even though my spinner is populated with these.

Its very strange as the list should have the objects stored.

Also, I have my adapter at the very top of the code in onCreate().

Comment: are u sure u getting data from firebase ???

Comment: Yes very sure. The data shows in the spinner. Plus when I uncomment the log it shows data being added to the list. Once it leaves the method though the list empties

Comment: where is ur shoring code? maybe that occur the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by shoring code?

Comment: "I am storing the University Objects in universitieslist", what do u mean by this line

Comment: I have University Object stored in Firebase. The Object contains the university name and an arraylist of type Programs. I am storing this Object of type University in an ArrayList which stores University Objects.

Comment: Consider adding the ChildEventListener  in the OnCreate() method of the activity that displays the items.(If fragment: in the onCreateView() method). As eventListeners in Firebase are asynchronous they tend to behave a bit tricky for us to understand. Another tip:add the adapter in the onChildAdded method. Let me know If you pulled it off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Hope it will work .. :)

```
private Arrylist<University > universityList = new ArryList<>();
private Arrylist<String> universitysName = new ArryList<>();

 mDatabase.getReference().child("path")
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
            University mUniversity  = dataSnapshot.getValue(University 
                                        .class);
            universityList.add(mUniversity);
            universitysName.add(mUniversity.getName);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I sill get a 0 sized arraylist

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the adapter, if you can see the logs but the adapter is not updating, then is because **the adapter is not being notified the data set has changed**

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if (dataSnapshot != null) {
        University mUniversity  = dataSnapshot.getValue(University 
                                    .class);
        universityList.add(mUniversity);
        universitysName.add(mUniversity.getName);
        //UPDATE YOUR ADAPTER HERE
        //spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

But I think the real problem is the origin of your current problem: You are getting each child. This is a way to do it, but for this case where you need all the data first and when that is ready show the spinner with the elements to the user, you should better get all the list elements in one query.

```
database.getReference("note-retrieve/Universities")..addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    University mUniversity  = dataSnapshot.getValue(University 
                                .class);
    universityList.add(mUniversity);
    universitysName.add(mUniversity.getName);
      //ONCE THIS IS DONE, THEN PASS THE ARRAY TO THE ADAPTER
                }
      //The loop here is over, so you can set the adapter with the full list of data/universities
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```